# Troubleshooting advice for: -bash: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: bash, binary, troubleshooting

I have a mining rig and am trying to run a program `./garlicoind`  but I get this error:

```
-bash: ./garicoind: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Is this a common problem? What does it indicate?

Comment: Maybe it is a binary for a different architecture. Look at `file garlicoind` to find out a bit more about that file.

Comment: For debugging https://askubuntu.com/questions/648555/bash-program-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program you have is most likely a binary compiled for a different architecture than the machine on which you're trying to run.

You can obtain the binary's architecture type by running

```
file garlicoind
```

and you can obtain your machine's architecture type by

```
uname -m
```

If they are different, you need either to get the correct binary for your architecture, or to get the code source of the program and compile it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! This was indeed the problem. I was trying to run a 32-bit program on my 64-bit machine