# How to install a compiled binary

Tags: debian, compiling, raspbian

I am still learning the basics of using Raspbian and having trouble while trying to install a program on Github with two options; source code or compiled binary.

Having put the source code method aside for receiving many errors, I have decided to try the supplied 'compiled binary' file. The file has no file type (it's called `owonb35`) and I do not know how to install it. I have used `apt-get` to install packages and `./configure`, `make` etc. to compile and install from source code a few times before, however this file does not seem to fit into either of those categories.

I decided to ask on here as opposed to raising an issue on Github as I assume the problem is my lack of knowledge as opposed to the files in the repository.

The repository I have downloaded file owonb35 from is:
https://github.com/DeanCording/owonb35

I hope I have provided enough information.

Comment: Have you tried `chmod +x owonb35` and `./owonb35`?

Comment: root@RPi:/home/pi/owonb35# chmod +x owonb35; 
 root@RPi:/home/pi/owonb35# owoncli;  bash: owoncli: command not found;  root@RPi:/home/pi/owonb35# ./owonb35;  bash: ./owonb35: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: Ok, it is likely that the compiled binary is not compiled for your architecture (ARM). You will need to either find another compiled binary that is compatible with your architecture or compile it yourself. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421049/troubleshooting-advice-for-bash-cannot-execute-binary-file-exec-format-error

Comment: Thank you, that sounds likely

Answer (score 2):

Pre-compiled binaries are just that - a portable binary that has already been compiled for a specific CPU architecture. That said, you need not technically *install* the binary, you only need to execute it. For example:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ chmod +x owonb35
[user@localhost ~]$ ./owonb35
---output from binary---
```

However, from the comments posted, it appears that the distributed binary was not compiled for your CPU architecture, in this case, `ARM` (standard with Raspberry Pi's). The person distributing this binary likely compiled it for a more standard architecture, for example, `x86`.

You can either find another distributed binary that has been compiled for ARM, or you can compile the source code on your local machine and create your own binary.